# java script import not working

Tags: javascript, import

Can you help me? , my import is not working

I have tried using babel but I dont know whats wrong

```
import Product from './cart'

E:\Guc\New Folder\shopping-cart\cart.test.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Product from './cart'
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Comment: show us the whole code please

Answer (score 0):

ES modules are available by default in Node.js 10 LTS. Starting from 8.5.0 you can use command line flag `--experimental-modules`